# Java, repeated logic block with different objects, cleaning code

Tags: java, generics

I want to clean up some code that makes my head hurt:

```
    activityStandardAttributeValue
            .setProduct((standardAttributeForm != null && standardAttributeForm
                    .getProduct() != null) ? standardAttributeForm
                            .getProduct()
                            : (groupedStandardAttributeForm != null ? groupedStandardAttributeForm
                                    .getProduct() : null));
    activityStandardAttributeValue
            .setProject((standardAttributeForm != null && standardAttributeForm
                    .getProject() != null) ? standardAttributeForm
                    .getProject()
                    : (groupedStandardAttributeForm != null ? groupedStandardAttributeForm
                    .getProject() : null));
```

I could simply change it to a easier to read form like:

```
    Product product = null;
    if(standardAttributeForm != null && standardAttributeForm.getProduct() != null) {
        product = standardAttributeForm.getProduct();
    } else if (groupedStandardAttributeForm != null && groupedStandardAttributeForm.getProduct() != null) {
        product = groupedStandardAttributeForm.getProduct();
    }
    activityStandardAttributeValue.setProduct(product);

    Project project = null;
    if(standardAttributeForm != null && standardAttributeForm.getProduct() != null) {
        project = standardAttributeForm.getProject();
    } else if (groupedStandardAttributeForm != null && groupedStandardAttributeForm.getProject() != null) {
        project = groupedStandardAttributeForm.getProject();
    }
```

The problem is that this same basic logic is repeated about 16 times for different properties and it isn't really much cleaner. I would like to create a generic way to do this without having to repeat the same basic logic. The tricky part is that standartAtributeForm or groupedStandardAttributeForm could be null.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're after some functional techniques.

Comment: @Alan  `Chain of Responsibilities` pattern might help

Comment: "I want to clean up some code that makes my head hurt:" Simply formatting it so that syntactically-related code is together would make it easier.

Comment: It looks like `product` and `project` have a lot in common. Why not create an interface? Further, looks like you could clean up some of this code by having your methods return Optional and running `.orElse()` on the result.

Comment: Make a common interface for Product and Project classes, implement it in both classes, make a method (takes Interface type as parameter) that will do that boolean evaluation and assignment and return appropriate value based on actual type of the object passed to the method (instanceof) and simply assign values to those variables like: Product product = methodName(appropriateParameters); and Project project = methodName(appropriateParameters);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, but it's too big to post in a comment (and relies on the formatting):

Simply using better formatting makes it easier to read. Here is your code passed through [google-java-format](https://github.com/google/google-java-format):

```
activityStandardAttributeValue.setProduct(
    (standardAttributeForm != null && standardAttributeForm.getProduct() != null)
        ? standardAttributeForm.getProduct()
        : (groupedStandardAttributeForm != null
            ? groupedStandardAttributeForm.getProduct()
            : null));
activityStandardAttributeValue.setProject(
    (standardAttributeForm != null && standardAttributeForm.getProject() != null)
        ? standardAttributeForm.getProject()
        : (groupedStandardAttributeForm != null
            ? groupedStandardAttributeForm.getProject()
            : null));
```

---

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
<T> getThing(Function<Form, T> extractor, T... forms) {
  for (T form : forms) {
    if (form != null) {
      T thing = extractor.apply(form);
      if (thing != null) return thing;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then:

```
activityStandardAttributeValue.setProduct(
    getThing(Form::getProduct, standardAttributeForm, groupedStandardAttributeForm));
activityStandardAttributeValue.setProject(
    getThing(Form::getProject, standardAttributeForm, groupedStandardAttributeForm));
```

Comment: the ternary nesting dolls are pretty ugly but this makes them look decent

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. I haven't played with Functional programming in Java at all, time to learn. A quick copy/paste didn't work but I'm sure I can get it working. Thanks.